# Correct Scope for vaadin 8 and spring

Tags: spring, vaadin, vaadin8, view-scope

I have a project, work with Vaadin 8.6 and Spring 5, and vaadin-spring 3.1.1
In this, there is `MainUI extends UI` that a bean with `scope="prototype"` initialized in `web-application-context.xml`

Problem: when we connect to project from more than one client (browser), there is only one session available.

we search and find some manuals, but we can not use it in our project

```
<bean id="mainUI" class="ir.fanap.fanitoring.ui.MainUI" scope="prototype">
```

[Vaadin Spring Add-on](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-spring.html)

how can we solve this problem? we did not use annotations for beans and all beans initialized in `web-application-context.xml`

Comment: "we did not use annotations for beans and all beans initialized in web-application-context.xml", I am curious to know why? Normally UI class is annotated with @SpringUI annotation, which also implies UIScope.

Comment: it's mean that remove bean from web-application-context and add annotation? and autowire all other beans that passed to it?

Comment: Basically yes, that is the way we usually do it.